# Chrome Extension not showing image

Tags: google-chrome, random

Hello everybody this is the project i am trying to make this extension will randomly select a picture from the list and show it. It shows it when you open the index.html in chrome but when its a extension there is nothing i am new in chrome extensions. Thank You
This is My Code

```
 <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var imageURLs = [
           "http://www.myserver.com/images/image1.png"
         , "http://www.myserver.com/images/image2.png"
         , "http://www.myserver.com/images/image3.png"
      ];
      function getImageTag() {
        var img = '<img src=\"';
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
        img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
        img += '\" alt=\"Some alt text\"/>';
        return img;
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write(getImageTag());
    </script>
    </body>

    <style>
    #container{
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
          body {
            font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
            font-size: 100%;
            -webkit-user-drag: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
          }
          #status {
            /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
            white-space: pre;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            overflow: hidden;
            max-width: 400px;
          }
        </style>
    <div id="container">
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no it just does not show the photo on the extension its only blank